# Notification System For A Social Networking Website

Tags: php, html, mysql, social-networking

Okay so I am using PHP MySQL .
I Want to Implement a Notification System For A Social Networking Site
Currently I have 2 Tables one For Posts containing  columns

1. 1. id //id of the post
2. 2. body//
3. 3. status // For Notifications
4. 4. user_id// id of the user

Whenever a preson comments or likes a particular post, 1 New record is inserted in the Notification table.
Notification Table Has the following columns

1. id// id of the notification
2. src_id // id of the post on which the user commented
3. type// like , comment etc
4. user_id //id of the user

So what the problem is that I want to fetch data from notifications table for which the user needs to be notified.

---

For Example
Mysql Query is

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE src_id IN ("244","245","249") order by src_id
```

For example I have some data like this in the notifications table

```
  id  type     user_id  src_id
  1   like      6       244
  2   comment   4       244
  3   like      1       249
  4   comment   8       249
  5   comment   9       245
  6   comment   3       244
  7   like      12      244
```

How Do i display it in php by grouping them by their src_id

So that I can generate something like this

> 4,3 commented on your post 244
>    12,6 liked your post 244
>    1 liked your post 249
>    8 commented on your post 249

*where `4,3,12,6,1,8` are user_ids*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see in mysql GROUP_CONCAT examples

edited:

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(`user_id`) as 'users'
    , `type`
    , `src_id` as 'post'
FROM `notifications`
WHERE `src_id` IN ("244","245","249")
group by `src_id`, `type`
ORDER BY `src_id`
```

Comment: how can i use that here ...pls specify

Comment: That Works Fine How Do I Access that Information through PHP

Comment: There are several methods to receive mysql data from php. Google its and choose. I advice mysqli for simple projects and PDO for complex..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `Sender` and `Receiver` column in your notifications table. The `Sender` column will contain the id of the user who performed the activity and `Receiver` column will contain the id of online user.

For example, User B commented on User A's post. Here, User B will be sender and User A will be receiver.

When receiving notifications for the online user, perform SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE Receiver='$online_user';
```

Example structure for notifications table:

```
CREATE TABLE notifications(
    NID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Sender INT NOT NULL,
    Receiver INT NOT NULL,
    Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Since INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Sender) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(Receiver) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```